# How to detect when a Ruby object is the right-hand side of a comparison?

Tags: ruby

I want to create an object in Ruby that can lazily execute some code when it is accessed, e.g. when it is inspected or compared. It's easy enough to intercept messages with `method_missing` (which would handle `object > 5`), but this doesn't cover all attempts to access the object.

To illustrate:

```
class Proxy
  def initialize(obj)
    @object = obj
  end

  def do_something
    self
  end

  def do_something_else
    self
  end

  def method_missing(msg, *args)
    puts "I'm here #{msg}"
    # Do something here
    @object.send(msg, *args)
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
proxy = Proxy.new(5)
proxy.do_something.do_something_else

proxy > 2
# I'm here >
# true

2 > proxy
# ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with Proxy failed
```

I'm wondering if there's an implementation of `Proxy` such that `2` actually sees `5` instead of the object.

Comment: The title and first sentence of your question doesn't match the last sentence of your question. Are you asking how to "lazily execute some code when [an object] is accessed," or are you asking how to use a Proxy object on the right-hand side of a comparison expression with a Fixnum? I'm having trouble understanding how those two very different problems are related.

Comment: Are they very different? Isn't the latter just an example of the former?

Comment: Not in any way that I can see. This seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What problem are you actually trying to solve? Making an object "lazily execute some code when it is accessed" is not part of the solution to using the object on the right-hand side of a comparison with a Fixnum.

Comment: I don't think there's a standard way to trap all calls to a particular Ruby object, but you cold make a proxy wrapper for it that intercepts and forwards all calls. Don't forget your proxy has to have almost no methods associated with it, you'll need to delete every single default method explicitly or use a base class like [BasicObject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/BasicObject.html)

Comment: @Jordan I feel like your response is unnecessarily pedantic. I'll change the title if it would please you, because a working solution to "the object on the right-hand side of a comparison with a Fixnum" is all I need to make progress.

Comment: @tadman thank you. I'll play around with BasicObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't "detect when a Ruby object is the right-hand side of a comparison." I'm going to infer from this, hopefully correctly, that the problem you're *actually* trying to solve is how to *use* a Ruby object in the right-hand side of a comparison with an object of a different type.

The answer is to define a `coerce` method. This method will be called automatically when the object is on the right-hand side of a comparison operator and an "incompatible" object is on the left-hand side. The LHS object will be supplied as an argument, and it's expected to return an array with two elements: "New" LHS and RHS values that *are* compatible. Using your Proxy example:

```
class Proxy
  def initialize(obj)
    @object = obj
  end

  def coerce(other)
    if other.is_a?(Fixnum)
      return [ other, @object.to_i ]
    end
    super
  end
end

proxy = Proxy.new(5)

2 > proxy
# => false
```

Of course, your `coerce` method will likely be more complex if you want your Proxy class to be able to "wrap" values other than Fixnums. For example, what will you do if `@object` is a String and `other` is a Float?

And, of course, this only handles when the object is the RHS. To make it work as the LHS as well you'll want to use the [Comparable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Comparable.html) mixin.

Comment: You were right...this did not help me solve X. But I do appreciate the guidance. I can at least handle the most common use cases with this.

Comment: Is there any safe way to accomplish this with `==`?

Comment: On the LHS you override the `==` method (`def ==(other) ...`). I don't think there's a way to do it on the RHS a la `coerce`, but I might be wrong. Maybe you could do something with `Module#prepend` on BasicObject?